# Cannot install platform plugind for android-28 in Android Studio 3.2 preview version

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to refactor my code to androidX. To do so android asked me to update the compiled version to at lease 28. So I changed my  compiled version to `compileSdkVersion 28` in `bulid.gradle`.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

But once I sync project I'm unable to download the platform plugins and the following error shows up in build window.

> Failed to find target with hash string 'android-28' in: /Users/work/Library/Android/sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compile version should be android-p. They're using the version name now.

```
compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
```

And target should be just P

```
targetSdkVersion 'P'
```

See [here](https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk) to know how to set up Android P SDK.

**Edit:**

If your getting an error/warning "*minSdkVersion (21) is greater than targetSdkVersion (1)*" this is done on purpose, see [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79477173).

As Android P is still Preview, the 'P' in the targetSdkVersion will work as a version 1. Once it's out of preview it will be replaced with the usual 28. For now, to fix this you'd need to raise the minSdkVersion to also 'P'.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But it gives this error after I change the tartgetSdkVersion to 'P'. **minSdkVersion (17) is greater than targetSdkVersion (1) for variant "release".**

Comment: Did you download the Android P Preview. and the Android SDK Build-Tools 28-rc2 ?

Comment: yes. I followed the link and downloaded Android P Preview & Android SDK Build-Tools 28-rc2